# Cannot set Word to be visible from a service

Tags: vb.net, service, ms-word

My goal is to create the Word object and get the PID of it.

The following code works from a form, however, when run from a service (in which each `thread` will have its own Word object), the `MSWord.Visible = True` doesn't work (it quietly just stays as `False`). The reason for trying to make it visible is that when Word is hidden, the `Process.MainWindowTitle` is blank.

```
Public Shared Function GetWordApp(ByRef ProcessID As Integer) As Object
        Dim MSWord As Object = Nothing

        Try
            MSWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

            MSWord.Visible = True

            Dim Caption As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString

            Try
                MSWord.Application.Caption = Caption

                For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")
                    If p.MainWindowTitle = Caption Then
                        ProcessID = p.Id
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                ProcessID = -999
            End Try

            MSWord.Visible = False

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error creating new instance of MS Word")

        End Try

        Return MSWord
    End Function
```

Comment: Don't do this with a Service. Services should not have any GUI. You can tick "interact with the desktop" on the service properties but this it a horrible solution.

Comment: @MattWilko I agree, but unfortunately the service requires Word to convert documents. I'll look into the "interact with the desktop", although your comment on it being a "horrible solution" is noted...

Comment: You can still manipulate a word doc without having to make it visible. Why do you need the Pid?

Comment: We don't know why, but after a while the Word seems to stop responding, in which case we have to close it and open a new instance. The PID allows me to safely close THAT Word without accidently closing one of our other Words (or the Client's Word if they use it on the system, which they shouldn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find Word's Process ID (Pid) by using the `FindWindow` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` API calls:

```
Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer

Public Shared Function GetWordApp(ByRef ProcessID As Integer) As Object
    Dim MSWord As Object = Nothing

    Try
        ProcessID = -1

        MSWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        MSWord.Visible = False

        Try
            Dim Caption As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
            MSWord.Application.Caption = Caption

            ' The Class name for Word is "OpusApp"
            Dim MSWindowHandle As System.IntPtr = FindWindow("OpusApp", Caption)

            GetWindowThreadProcessId(MSWindowHandle, ProcessID)

        Catch ex As Exception
            ProcessID = -1

        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error creating new instance of MS Word")

    End Try

    Return MSWord
End Function
```